# layout - show the latter coded div at top without absolute positioning

Tags: css, layout, positioning

If it is, how would it be possible to show the latter coded at top without absolute positioning via *pure CSS* (No js and ancient browsers like ie6 are none of my concern)?

I require 3 main parts

1. menu (visible at top but coded after left or left&right)
2. left (coded first (at top most) cause it's the place my article's html exist)
3. right (secondary importance things)

Sorry for that I couldn't try anything cause I have no idea how no-abs-positioning  solution would exist, if exists.

one may say that *"what is wrong with abs positioning?"* Nothing is wrong with abs positioning however I just want to learn.

thanks, best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change the ordering of elements with the use of Flexbox, if your target browsers support it http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* Flexbox defaults to a row layout, so we set it to column so the .content and .menu elements stack. */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  /* Distribute elements inside .content with respect to their space between the elements */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  /* Forces the elements ordering to the top */
  order: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #dedede;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #aeaeae;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    Menu
  </div>
</div>
```